# SKCameraNode Lags Behind When Player Moves

Tags: xcode, swift, camera, sprite-kit

I am currently trying to have my Camera follow my player "orb" whenever the player is moved. I've set the Camera's position to move to the orb's x position whenever the orb is moved, however for some reason, as the orb is moved quickly, the SKCameraNode glitches and stutters as if it is trying to catch up to the node's position. I've read that it's because the physics runs after the actual update(), but I have no idea on how to resolve the issue. Is there any way to fix this problem?

NOTE: I don't want the camera to always center on the "orb", but rather delay a little as it follows the orb, to give it a free-moving feel to it. (if that makes sense)

```
    import SpriteKit

    class GameScene: SKScene {

    var orb = SKSpriteNode()
    var Touch: UITouch?
    let theCamera: SKCameraNode = SKCameraNode()

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

        let orbTexture1 = SKTexture(imageNamed:"orb.png")

        orb = SKSpriteNode(texture: orbTexture1)
        orb.name = "Orb"
        orb.position = CGPointMake(300, 95)
        self.addChild(orb)

        theCamera.position = CGPointMake(300, 0)
        theCamera.name = "Camera"
        self.addChild(theCamera)
        self.camera = theCamera

    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch in touches {
            if nodeAtPoint(touch.locationInNode(self)).name == "Orb" {
                Touch = touch as UITouch
            }
        }
    }

    override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch in touches {
            if Touch != nil {
                if touch as UITouch == Touch! {
                    let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
                        orb.position = location
                }
            }
        }
    }


override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */

    let action = SKAction.moveToX(orb.position.x, duration: 0.5)
    theCamera.runAction(action)

    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use SKActions inside the update Function.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this by using the didSimulatePhysics method not the update method .

Replace the update method with this :

```
>     override func didSimulatePhysics() {
>         let action = SKAction.moveToX(orb.position.x, duration: 0.5)
>         theCamera.runAction(action)
>     }
```

Comment: This would not help at all,  the only thing you are doing here is delaying the problem till closer to the end of the update, the stutter will still happen.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this affect because on every update, you are attaching a new SKAction to your camera.  This means in 1 second, your camera is being told 60 times to move to the orb position.  This means you have 60 actions controlling how your sprite should be moving, and they are all battling to get priority.

What you need to do is remove the previous move action, or let the previous action finish.

To remove the action, you can call `removeAllActions()` or `removeAction(forKey:)`

This of course means you need to first assign a key to your action, `theCamera.runAction(action, withKey:"cameraMove")`

Now a shorthand way to replace an action is to just call `theCamera.runAction(action, withKey:"cameraMove")`, because the new action will replace the existing action, there by removing it.

Your other option is to check if the action exists with `action(forKey:)`  Then determine if you need to process further action.